# Loki's punishment

Tags: marvel, avengers, thor-marvel, loki

Would Loki have been punished at the end of the "Thor" movie had he not disappeared?

I am sure he will get punished after returning to Asgard (at the end of the Avengers movie), as he has been a lot more cruel in the second movie!

Comment: Were this myth!Loki, as opposed to Marvel!Loki, he would be likely to be blamed and punished *regardless* of whether things were actually his fault.  Myth!Loki gets a pretty rough deal.  Marvel!Loki is taken back to Asgard at the end of *The Avengers* explicitly to face punishment for his crimes in *both* events - what he did in *Thor* essentially had not yet caught up with him until then.

Answer (score 5):

At the end of Thor, Loki is seen falling into space. Post-credits, he is seen appearing in a SHIELD facility on Earth, covertly subverting SHIELD's research projects for his own ends to create a portal between worlds.

It's not clear if Loki is actually on Earth or not, as in the Avengers movie, he is shown as being beamed back to Earth by the Tesseract.

My suspicion is that Thor and Odin were unable to find or capture Loki in-between the events of the Thor and Avengers movies, and even if they had, punishment might have been "soft" because:

1. He initially allowed the Frost Giants to his planet (at the beginning of the Thor movie) to simply spoil Thor's coronation.
2. He hid the truth about Odin's situation from Thor when Thor was on Earth, but again, to claim power.
3. He led the leader of the Frost Giants to Odin's bedroom, but destroyed the Frost Giant before Odin was hurt.

In the Avengers movie, on the other hand, he is indeed vastly more cruel, kills and maims people, and wages war on an entire planet. Way more cruel, and he's likely to be more severely punished.

Comment: To be honest I imagine that Odin cares a lot more that Loki let Laufey get so close to killing him, than he cares that he wages some war on some planet of mortals.